# Angular 8 how to set background using [style]

Tags: angular, property-binding

I am learning angular to set style using angular way so I have create below code. I am trying to set background using below code - but its not working as expected. How to set background using below syntax with [style]? 
      I am creating demo with angular 8.

```
<code>
   <div [style.background-color]='red'> 
      a
   </div>
</code>
```

Comment: [style.background-color]=“'red'” (note the extra quotes)

Comment: @NicholasK bharat appears to have a history of posting low quality questions and never accepts answers. It's very frustrating, time-wasting, and clearly not a successful way of learning a new language

Answer (score 2):

> `<div [style.background-color]='red'>`

means that Angular is looking for a *variable* named red, which it doesn't find hence the style doesn't get applied.

Use:

> `<div [style.background-color]="'red'">`

which informs Angular to use the *string* value which is evaluates to red.

---

You can also use the following syntax to avoid any confusion:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ background: 'red'}">
```

Answer (score 1):

For a background color inline style you would need: `[style.background-color]="'red'"`